# anime js onclick animate a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this effect of [anime js](http://animejs.com/)

```
$(function(){

    var bouncingBall = anime({
      targets: '.box',
      translateY: '50vh',
      duration: 300,
      loop: 4,
      direction: 'alternate',
      easing: 'easeInCubic'
    });

});
```

How can I run the animation only when I'm clicking on a button, 
so let's say I have in my HTML:

```
<div class="box">Button</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it, In the javascript I should have had this line
`document.querySelector('.box').onclick = bouncingBall.play;`

so when I click on the class `box` it will animate the `bouncingBall`

Answer (score 2):

Your js code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
    var bouncingBall = anime({
      targets: '.box',
      translateY: '50vh',
      duration: 300,
      loop: 4,
      direction: 'alternate',
      easing: 'easeInCubic',
      autoplay: false //if you don't want play animation on page load
    });

    document.querySelector('.box').onclick = bouncingBall //onclick event
});
```

Documentation: http://animejs.com/documentation/#playPause